# Post in Wordpress from a Contact Form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've been using a simple plugin in my Wordpress page, **POSTIE**, that works well when I send an email from my Gmail account and publish it as a new post.

But now I want to create this new posts from a Contact Form 7 from my web. But it doesn't work at all. I receive my contact forms mails in my inbox, but then they're not posting as a new post.

Is there a problem that we can't post from our own server or something like that? How can I create a new post from a contact form 7 in Wordpress?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see a way how to do it (but I think it's a bad idea to do it throw CF7), anyway:

You need use a few hooks. One from CF7 to trigger when you form are sent, the list of hooks are [there](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/#index=a), I guess **wpcf7_before_send_mail** .

Ans then insert information with **[wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)** hook.

Comment: Which are the other ways you recommend to do it?

Comment: For now, I see only that one... but it should be enough if you make everything right